# What is the equivalent of "task_struct" in linux's <linux/sched.h> for Mac OS?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, macos, process-management

I want to understand the Process Control block of Mac OS and Linux. For Lionux it was pretty strightforward, there was a post here asking about the same thing and someone replied to go take a look at "task_struct" in <linux/sched.h>. However i am finding it more difficult to find the equivalent information for Mac OS, someone in apple's developer forum asked a similar question and got told to look at proc_info.h and proc.h, but i am lost as to which struct i should be looking at. Is there a task_struct equivalent in Mac OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of Mac OS but… a couple about FreeBSD. Hope it will match.

You got it right looking at the `task_struct` in Linux because it's the basic unit of scheduling in Linux.

The basic unit of scheduling in FreeBSD is the `thread`.

Linux represents processes (and threads) by `task_struct` structures.
A single-threaded process in Linux has a single `task_struct`.

A single-threaded process in FreeBSD has a `proc` struct, a `thread` struct, and a `ksegrp` struct.
(The `ksegrp` is a "kernel scheduling entity group.")

At the end of the day both OSes schedule threads, where a thread is a `thread` structure in FreeBSD, and a `task_struct` in Linux.

Therefore, yes indeed, follow the advice and first have a look to proc.h

Comment: thanks a lot!!!